# How to prove sampled sinc function is not absolutely summable

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

In study of digital filters, we encounter the function $\text{sinc}(x)$ both in continuous domain or as sampled sequence $$\text{sinc}(kn), n\in Z, k\in (0,\pi)$$ many times it is needed to prove that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty}|\frac{\sin(\omega_c n)}{\pi n}|$ diverges.
I read that for continuous-domain, we can show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\frac{\sin x}{x}|$ diverges, but I am clueless how to show the same for the sampled sequence, for special values of k like $\frac{\pi}{2}$, we can use results for some known sequences but I do not know what to do in case of general $k,$ I thought that we could assume $\sin(kn)$ takes a minimum value $m_0$ checked over all integers, then we could say $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty}|\frac{\sin(\omega_c n)}{\pi n}|\geq m_0\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty}|\frac{1}{\pi n}|$
and we know the latter is divergent, but I don't know if the claiming that a minimum value can be found when the domain is countably infinite is correct or not.

I request a proof that absolute sum of this sequence is divergent for all $k \in (0,\pi).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with $k \in (0,\pi)$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{|\sin kn|}{n} \geqslant\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\sin^2 kn}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1- \cos 2kn}{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2n}- \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos 2kn}{2n}$$

As $m \to \infty$, the first sum on the RHS diverges to $+\infty$ and the second sum converges (by the Dirichlet test). The limit as $m \to \infty$ of the partial sum sequence on the LHS must be $+\infty$.